# Are there any difficult integrals workbooks?

Tags: reference-request, online-resources

I'm a physics student with interests in mathematics and enjoy doing integrals by hand. I have been looking for a workbook or place with lists of difficult integrals I can try and do for practice. I am hoping for integrals with trig substitutions, Fourier transformations, complex analysis, integration by parts, differentiating under the integral, etc. I need practice in advanced techniques in integration and am looking for a book or place with lists of integrals that will allow me to practice.

Comment: Some (problems at the bottom of the page): http://www.mit.edu/~same/integrationbee.html http://web.mit.edu/abhinavk/www/integrationbee/qual2012.pdf

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the following:

Inside Interesting Integrals: A Collection of Sneaky Tricks, Sly Substitutions, and Numerous Other Stupendously Clever, Awesomely
Wicked, and ..., by Paul J. Nahin.  ISBN-13: 978-1493912766

Irresistible Integrals: Symbolics, Analysis and Experiments in the
Evaluation of Integrals, by George Boros.  ISBN-13: 978-0521796361

Enjoy!  :-)

Abe M.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer **Thomas Calculus** by **George V Thomas, Pearson Publications**. I suggest its 11'th edition ( Now 12'th edition available ).The book provide a vast number of solved problems and hundreds of exercise questions (Answer keys also available ).These are the section I found, which will help you.

1. CHAPTER 5--INTEGRATION
2. CHAPTER 6--APPLICATIONS OF DEFINITE INTEGRALS
3. CHAPTER 8--TECHNIQUES OF INTEGRATION
4. CHAPTER 9--FURTHER APPLICATIONS OF INTEGRATION
5. CHAPTER 15--MULTIPLE INTEGRALS
6. CHAPTER 16--INTEGRATION IN VECTOR FIELDS

Comment: Comment below for any further information